# Kubernetes master at https://localhost:6443. Not able to login

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I've installed docker for desktop v2.0.0.3. I'm able to see cluster info using kubectl command. `kubectl cluster-info` which gives
`Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6443`.
Now when I try to login to **https://localhost:6443** it doesn't ask for credentials and shows me 404 forbidden message . below is the entire trace -

```
{   "kind": "Status",   "apiVersion": "v1",   "metadata": {
       },   "status": "Failure",   "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",   "reason": "Forbidden",  "details": {
       },   "code": 403 }
```

Comment: Does `kubectl config current-context` point to `docker-desktop`, or somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes to docker-for-desktop

Answer (score 3):

You need a bearer token or a client certificate for accessing the kubernetes API.

Easiest option is to access it via [kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/http-proxy-access-api/) wherein kubectl will make use of kubeconfig to perform the authentication so you don't need to provide any certificate or token separately.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following command; which will make kubectl behave as reverse proxy:

```
$ kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
```

You can use any other available port, then access the kubernetes api server on that port.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

**create a service-account-token secret:**
[Secrets | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

**show any secrets:**

```
kubectl get secret
```

**show base64 encoded token:**

```
kubectl get secret [secret from above] -o yaml
```

**save token from above in file then decode:**

```
echo [token from above] > junkfile.txt
base64 junkfile.txt -d
```

**make an api call:**

```
curl https://localhost:6443/apis --header "Authorization: Bearer [decoded token from above]" -k
```

**note:**
"When creating a Pod, Kubernetes automatically creates a service account Secret and automatically modifies your Pod to use this Secret. The service account token Secret contains credentials for accessing the API.

The automatic creation and use of API credentials can be disabled or overridden if desired. However, if all you need to do is securely access the API server, this is the recommended workflow."